# Copy Multiple Files with Same Characters to a Single File

Tags: batch-processing, dos

I have a lot of files that need to be joined. Existing file naming structure is 20130514ABCD.txt where the file naming convention is year, month, date, city. I would like to merge files with same last four characters (i.e same city) into one.

I am only able to move the city to a folder created for each city. This is not I want..

```
@echo off

pushd pathname
for /f %%F in ('dir/b/a-d *.txt') do call :sub1 %%F
goto :eof

:sub1
set name=%1
md %name:~9,12%
move %* %name:~9,12%
```

What I need is script equivalent to `C:\>copy *CITY.TXT to CITY.txt`, where CITY name is a variable.

Comment: Two questions: are all cities in the same folder?  Does every city have a common date - so I could ask for 29130514*.txt and get one file for each city.  ??

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** This works here with files as you've stated.

```
@echo off
pushd "pathname"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do call :sub1 "%%F"
popd
pause
goto :eof

:sub1
set "name=%~1"
set "cityname=%name:~8,-4%"
if exist "%cityname%\" goto :EOF
echo processing "%cityname%"
md "%cityname%" 2>nul
copy /b "????????%cityname%.txt" "%cityname%\%cityname%.txt" >nul
```

Comment: All cities (with different dates) are in the same folder. Date is also a variable, meaning the file name could be 20100111CITA.txt, 20110214CTTB.txt etc.

Comment: Try the code above.  The city folders will be created, and should not pre-exist else it will skip the files.

Comment: It prompts a message "The system cannot find the path specified. Press any key to continue....", not sure what went wrong.

Comment: The path error is from the "pathname" which I left in from your original code.  Did you run it in the folder with the files?  It should still have processed all the files.